# jqGrid event:jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow rowdata empty?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have following event binding code. When i try to save the row the event function gets fired but i do not get any row data? **i have to get entire data and iterate to locate id. Is this correct???**

```
$("#jqGrid").bind("jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow", function (e, rowid, orgClickEvent) {
    console.log("[Start]jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow");
    console.log(rowid);
    console.log(orgClickEvent);
    console.log(e);

    var data = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
      if(item._id_ === rowid){
        console.log(item);
      }
    });    


    console.log("[End]jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow");
    return e.result === undefined ? true : e.result;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please include always the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

In any way the parameters

```
$("#jqGrid").bind("jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow",
    function (e, rowid, jqXhrOrBool, postData, options) {
        var item = $(this).jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid);
        //...
    }
);
```

Where the 3-d parameter is Boolean in case of saving of local data and [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) in case of saving data to the server via Ajax request. The parameter `postData` contains the modified data, which you probably need. If you feed *all data* about the row instead of only editable fields, then you can use `getLocalRow` to get the reference to the item of internal `data`, which represent full local row data.

I tested just now the event `jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow` in free jqGrid 4.13.6, which I develop, and the event really contains the parameters, which I described above.